# Testing if a random signal was modified or if it contains noise

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis

Given a random signal, is there a method of finding if it was modified or if it contains noise if you don't know the original signal?

E.g.: given a random image, can I find out if it was modified if I don't know the original?

Comment: what do you *know* about the random signal? Kind of obviously, if you know *nothing*, then nothing can tell a noisy signal from a non-noisy signal, because every signal is equally likely. But given you're asking this, I *bet* you know something about the signal you just forget to mention.

Comment: Only its final form. It's just a curiosity if there is something like a mathematical condition that needs to be met or another type of method

Comment: no, if you know nothing about a signal, that means you know nothing. You hence can't tell signal from noise.

Comment: @Robert-NicolaeSolca Consider this scenario: I give you a noisy image. There's no way to know if the noise is artificial or not. This is the same reason it's impossible to denoise an AM signal: the broadcaster _may_ be transmitting a noisy signal on purpose! There's no way to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to say for sure. But you can make some assumptions about the signal.

If we assume that signal is not compressed and is not encrypted, you can assume that entropy gets higher as more noise is added. That is, a photo of a beach will take up less kb when compressed, than a white noice picture. If lossless compression is used.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity
This is a way to estimate entropy from theoretical point of view. Practical is lossless compression. This is the only thing that fits your question exactly.

If we assume that signal is sending the data at much lower frequency than carrier frequency, which is the case for almost all consumer grade tech, and our sampling rate is much faster than the cartier wave of the signal, which is very expensive tech, we can search for the carrier wave itself. The ratio of noise to signal within a single symbol will indicate the noise. This will work with any information being sent, even encrypted. Frequency hopping is seen as particular time on a particular frequency. Like 1ms on frequency of 2.396mhz. Ultrawideband is seen as separate pulses with repetition after a natural number of pauses. like delta pulse after 1ns*N, where N is 1,2,3,4... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_wave

Second case is just a special case of the first. You can collect the samples and try to compress them, and use the resulting size reduction as a rough estimate on amount of non-natural signals.

There is theoretical way to transmit information on a radio frequency that will not be detected quickly, like in examples above. It would require to operate frequency much lower than the carrier frequency, or maximum switching frequency of the device, emit wideband signal, emit signal that is below natural noise level for a desired target distance (still can be detected if detector is closer than that range), use encryption to make signal look random, use direct sequence spread spectrum, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-sequence_spread_spectrum or similar technique to code 1 bit of data as many bit of output signal, use precise clocks since normal synchronisation methods would be visible. As far as I know noone bothers with such extremes and almost all of our radio signals can be detected by patterns charecteristical to that modulation. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation

If we asume this picture was taken by a camera, then even this extreme method wont protect from much simpler detection methods, such as retroreflection of the optical system (camera)
https://jc6guaarxlwqeirmsf35gvp7ki-adwhj77lcyoafdy-ru-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB)

And even without optics a pcb parts nearby the camera can be found using metal detector, and in particular ringing of its antena, even if its not working. But this only works in close proximity, less than 1m.

You may want to specify the device you are talking about, to get more precise answer. Since there isnt much to be done with the image alone.

TLDR: it comes down to a lot of tricks. To select the trick for your case, more information about the system is needed. One that sort of fits sometimes is entropy estimating.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You have to start with some prior knowledge of the signal and of the noise.  Your signal may be my noise, and visa-versa.